# MPI in C : Scatterv doesn't work

Tags: c, mpi

My `MPI_Scatterv` doesn't always work. I get an error message

> status of rank 0: killed by signal 11.

Below is my code:

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <math.h>
#include "bmp.h"
using namespace std;
//定義平滑運算的次數
#define NSmooth 1000
BMPHEADER bmpHeader;                        
BMPINFO bmpInfo;
RGBTRIPLE **BMPSaveData = NULL;                                               
RGBTRIPLE **BMPData = NULL;  
RGBTRIPLE **BMPRecv = NULL;
int readBMP( char *fileName);        //read file
int saveBMP( char *fileName);        //save file
void swap(RGBTRIPLE *a, RGBTRIPLE *b);
RGBTRIPLE **alloc_memory( int Y, int X );        //allocate memory
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
char *infileName = "input.bmp";
char *outfileName = "output2.bmp";
int rem, *displs, new_height, width, id, process, sum=0, *sendcounts;
int count = 3;
int lengths[3] = {1, 1, 1};
MPI_Aint offsets[3] = {0, 1, 2};
MPI_Datatype types[3] = {MPI_BYTE, MPI_BYTE, MPI_BYTE};
MPI_Datatype datatype;
MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &id);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &process);
MPI_Type_struct(count, lengths, offsets, types, &datatype);
MPI_Type_commit(&datatype);
double startwtime = 0.0, endwtime=0;
startwtime = MPI_Wtime();
if(id == 0)
{

        if ( readBMP( infileName) )
        {
            cout << "Read file successfully!!" << endl;
            rem = (bmpInfo.biHeight*bmpInfo.biWidth)%process;
            new_height = bmpInfo.biHeight / process;
            width = bmpInfo.biWidth;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Read file fails!!" << endl;
            MPI_Finalize();
            return 0;
        }      
}
MPI_Bcast(&rem, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
MPI_Bcast(&new_height, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
MPI_Bcast(&width, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
sendcounts = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int ) *process);
displs = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int ) *process);
for (int i =0; i < process; i++)
{
    sendcounts[i] = new_height*width;
    if (rem > 0)
    {
        sendcounts[i]++;
        rem--;
    }
    displs[i] = sum;
    sum += sendcounts[i];
}
BMPRecv = alloc_memory(new_height, width);

#####MPI_Scatterv(&BMPSaveData, sendcounts, displs, datatype, &BMPRecv,   (new_height*width), datatype, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
BMPData = alloc_memory(new_height, width);
for(int count = 0; count < NSmooth ; count ++)
{

        swap(BMPRecv,BMPData);

        for(int i = 0; new_height ; i++)
        {
            for(int j =0; j<width ; j++)
            {

                int Top = i>0 ? i-1 : new_height-1;
                int Down = i<new_height-1 ? i+1 : 0;
                int Left = j>0 ? j-1 : width-1;
                int Right = j<width-1 ? j+1 : 0;

                BMPRecv[i][j].rgbBlue =  (double) (BMPData[i][j].rgbBlue+BMPData[Top][j].rgbBlue+BMPData[Down][j].rgbBlue+BMPData[i][Left].rgbBlue+BMPData[i][Right].rgbBlue)/5+0.5;
                BMPRecv[i][j].rgbGreen =  (double) (BMPData[i][j].rgbGreen+BMPData[Top][j].rgbGreen+BMPData[Down][j].rgbGreen+BMPData[i][Left].rgbGreen+BMPData[i][Right].rgbGreen)/5+0.5;
                BMPRecv[i][j].rgbRed =  (double) (BMPData[i][j].rgbRed+BMPData[Top][j].rgbRed+BMPData[Down][j].rgbRed+BMPData[i][Left].rgbRed+BMPData[i][Right].rgbRed)/5+0.5;
            }
        }
}
MPI_Gatherv(&BMPRecv, (new_height*width), datatype, &BMPSaveData, sendcounts, displs, datatype, 0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
if (id == 0)
{
    if ( saveBMP( outfileName ) )
    {
        cout << "Save file successfully!!" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Save file fails!!" << endl;
    }   
    endwtime = MPI_Wtime();
    cout << "The execution time = "<< endwtime-startwtime <<endl ;
}
    free(BMPData);
    free(BMPSaveData);
    free(BMPRecv);
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```